# Multi stem jquery form not working

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-plugins, multi-step

Below is my multistep form but it is not working properly,what it should happen is to go to next fields for input when next is clicked but when i click next it stays in that form nothing happens.It stays in the same page and even if next is clicked it is being just clicked with no function at all

```
    <html>
    <head> 
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //jQuery timevar current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
   var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches
 $(".next").click(function(){
if(animating) return false;
animating = true;

current_fs = $(this).parent();
next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

//activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
$("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

//show the next fieldset
next_fs.show(); 
//hide the current fieldset with style
current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
        //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
        //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
        scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
        //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
        left = (now * 50)+"%";
        //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
        opacity = 1 - now;
        current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
        next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
    }, 
    duration: 800, 
    complete: function(){
        current_fs.hide();
        animating = false;
    }, 
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
 });
    $(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;
    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();
    //de-activate current step on progressbar
    $("#progressbar                                                   li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");
    //show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
            scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
            left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'left': left});
            previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity':                                            opacity});
        }, `enter code here`
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});
$(".submit").click(function(){
    return false;
})
</script>
<style>/*importing Sniglet*/
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sniglet");
/*basic reset*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}
body {
    padding-top: 100px;
    background: hsl(120, 40%, 40%);
    font-family: Sniglet;
}
main {
width: 500px; margin: 0 auto; padding-bottom: 10px;
background: white; border-radius: 3px; overflow: hidden;
}
h1 {
font-size: 24px; font-weight: normal;
background: hsl(120, 40%, 95%); color: hsl(120, 40%, 40%);
text-align: center; 
padding: 20px 0; margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.flp {padding: 0 50px;}
/*Let's place the label over the input*/
.flp div {position: relative; margin-bottom: 30px;}

.flp input, .flp label {
width: 400px; display: block;
font: inherit; font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px;
/*fixed height for FF line height issue. 
height = 24(lineheight) + 10*2(padding) + 2(border)*/
height: 46px;
border: 1px solid #999;
}
.flp input {padding: 10px; outline: none; border-radius: 3px;}
.flp label {
position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;
/*left/right padding will be 2px less, adjusted by padding on .ch*/
padding: 10px 8px;
border-color: transparent; color: #666;
cursor: text;
}

/*label styles*/
.ch {
display: block; float: left;
position: relative; /*for upward animation*/
background: white; 
}
.ch:first-child {padding-left: 2px;}
.ch:last-child {padding-right: 2px;}

/*active input label*/
.focussed {
/*when any input is already focussed clicking on it(label) again won't do                         anything*/
pointer-events: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- multistep form -->
<form id="msform">
<!-- progressbar -->
<ul id="progressbar">
    <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
    <li>Personal Details</li>
</ul>
<!-- fieldsets -->
<fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
    <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next"         />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
    <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button"     value="Previous" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button"     value="Submit" />
</fieldset>
</form>
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- jQuery easing plugin -->
<script src="http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, I am assuming that you didn't paste everything because you don't have an opening html tag at the top, also your javascript is not valid, and does not have an opening script tag.  Your problem though, it probably the fact that your JS is at the top of your document and not wrapped in a document ready.  http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: some code were mistakenly in part of question i have edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your Javascript in a document ready.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    //jQuery timevar current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
   var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches
 $(".next").click(function(){
if(animating) return false;
animating = true;

current_fs = $(this).parent();
next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

//activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
$("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

//show the next fieldset
next_fs.show(); 
//hide the current fieldset with style
current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
        //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
        //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
        scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
        //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
        left = (now * 50)+"%";
        //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
        opacity = 1 - now;
        current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
        next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
    }, 
    duration: 800, 
    complete: function(){
        current_fs.hide();
        animating = false;
    }, 
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
 });
    $(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;
    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();
    //de-activate current step on progressbar
    $("#progressbar                                                   li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");
    //show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
            scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
            left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'left': left});
            previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity':                                            opacity});
        }, `enter code here`
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});
$(".submit").click(function(){
    return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: You are also trying to use jQuery before you load it. You  can't have $ until after <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>